# LM not working (Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) invalid model formula in ExtractVars

Tags: r

Trying to run the function

```
CatFit1<-lm(PRICE~BATHS+BEDS+ 'SQUARE FEET'+CatLotData2$LotCat+ 
            'YEAR BUILT'+CatLotData2$NeighCat, data=CatLotData2)
```

but getting this error message:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

Anyone have an idea of the problem?

Comment: Can you please include the output from `dput(head(CatLotData2))` so we can hel;p? Edit your question to include it, don't put it as a comment

Answer (score 2):

If there are spaces in the variable names surround them with backticks, not single quotes.  For example,

```
PRICE ~ BATHS + BEDS + `SQUARE FEET`
```

The other possibility is to change the names so that they don't have spaces in them in the first place.